# Google Sheets, fill data from form sheet into specific cells on other sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to coding in general (other than experience with MATLAB which I don't think counts) but I'm starting with trying to code in the Google Sheets API for some advanced functionality.

The code I'm trying to write is for a spreadsheet that I track all my car expenses on. I have it doing a bunch of number crunching for MPG currently, but don't want to have to find the row and column each time to enter the date. Instead I'd like one sheet that is clean and simple that I enter the variables on (Miles driven, gallons pumped, price per gallon, estimated MPG from the car computer) and it fills the other sheets in the document with that information automatically when I hit save, then clears the form so I can do it again next time.

Here is what I have so far.

```
function submitData() {
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName('Fill-Up'); //Form Sheet
var datasheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Mileage Stats'); //Data Sheet 1
var datasheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Costs and Savings'); //Data Sheet 2

//Input Values 1
var values1 = [[formSS.getRange('B3').getValue(),
             formSS.getRange('B6').getValue()]];

datasheet1.getRange(datasheet1.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 2).setValues(values1);

//Input Values 2
var values2 = [[formSS.getRange('B4').getValue(),
             formSS.getRange('B5').getValue()]];

datasheet2.getRange(datasheet2.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 2).setValues(values2);
}
```

It works with the exception of two issues that I haven't been able to solve yet.

1) It writes the information to a new row at the bottom of the page, not the next empty row.

2) It isn't writing the information in B6 to the correct cell. I want B3 written to column B in "Mileage Stats" sheet, and it is, B4 is written to column B in "Costs and Savings" as I want, and B5 is written to column C in "Costs and Savings" as I want, but B6 is written to column C in "Mileage Stats" but I want it in column G, and can't figure out how to change that with my current code, or any other code I can find.

Any help anyone can give would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any `ArrayFormulas` on the sheets that you are trying to use `getLastRow()`? If so, `ArrayFormula` will add data into the cells for the whole range.

You may want to look at using the `Sheet.appendRow()` method like below and remove all the empty rows on your data sheets. `appendRow()` will add a new row at the bottom of the sheet with that data passed to the method.

```
    datasheet1.appendRow(values1);

    datasheet2.appendRow(values2);
```

Comment: Yes, the other cells in my row have formulas in them. Column A is the only one in the row that is auto populated. I wrote some code to auto populate column A with the date when column B of the row has data input into it. Then column C thru column F have formulas to calculate Miles driven on the tank, MPG, etc.

Comment: Link to the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEP8ClBYz60uTQZCbLDZHHOdOduUAUMU7Xi8r9KzRhU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Cells with functions are counted as data cells, that's why you're inserting the rows at the bottom of the sheet. To solve this, you can use [getNextDataCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection) method to a column range without functions (e.g. a cell in column B), which returns the last cell with data for a given direction. I tested the below code and worked for inserting the data in the last row with data in column B:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName('Fill-Up'); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Mileage Stats'); //Data Sheet 1
  var datasheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Costs and Savings'); //Data Sheet 2

  //Input Values 1
  var values1 = [[formSS.getRange('B3').getValue(),
                  formSS.getRange('B6').getValue()]];
  var lastRowInB = datasheet1.getRange("B6").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getLastRow();
  datasheet1.getRange(lastRowInB+1, 2, 1, 2).setValues(values1);

  //Input Values 2
  var values2 = [[formSS.getRange('B4').getValue(),
                  formSS.getRange('B5').getValue()]];
  lastRowInB = datasheet1.getRange("B7").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getLastRow();
  datasheet2.getRange(lastRowInB+1, 2, 1, 2).setValues(values2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works almost perfectly.

I still can't figure out how to make the B6 value into the correct cell, but it is writing to the correct row.

I tried breaking the B3 and B6 values out into two variables, but I clearly don't know what I'm doing because that broke it. This also broke my date script, but I just added writing the B2 value into Column a on Datasheet1, and having the date value autofill with the =Today() function, so that was easy to fix.

Comment: What's the exact problem? You should read the [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) method documentation to understand how you're getting the cell to set the values to and  thus being able to fix it as you want. Also read the documentation for the [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) method or [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) which might be more helpful in your case.